# Meaning of admit light?

Tags: meaning, phrases

The definition of "chink" cited [**here**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chink) is

> A narrow opening, typically one that admits light

What is that `admit light`?

Comment: See Collins [admit](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/admit) sense 1, *to let in* light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*admit light* means *allow light to enter* (generally where it is otherwise blocked)

Defined by Merriam-Webster at http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/admit as

> 2. a :  to allow entry (as to a place, fellowship, or privilege)

.

You can imagine in the definition of chink you have given from Oxford Dictionaries at http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chink that

> a chink in the curtains

describes a small gap between two closed curtains that allows a small amount of light to come through.